# User role templates

Tags: templates, user-roles, author, template-hierarchy, author-template

I'm currently using the `author.php` template to display a frontend archive of users' posts from all roles. I've now created a new user role ("trainer") that needs to have a completely different frontend template to the other user roles.

My instinct was that I would be able to create a template with a naming convention like `user-trainer.php` or `trainer.php` that would only apply to users with the "trainer" role, but after looking through the Wordpress docs this does not appear to be a thing.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could achieve this other than just doing an `if` statement that checks the user role in `author.php`?

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this?

Comment: @ArsalanMithani So that the trainer users can have a different front end template for their "archive" page. Other user roles have a basic template in which their name and posts are displayed, the trainers have a vastly different template.